# FCM token is not getting generated in few devices

Tags: android, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` method to generate device token. I know this method is deprecated, but I am keen to find the exact RCA for the issue.

When I am using this method in emulator, it is working fine and returning token with all emulator variation tried with multiple emulators.

I tried debugging with android phone it is returning device token. But Our application runs on Zebra TC57 device and there it is not working and method is returning null.
This works in some device and not works in some device. I have one device where it's not working to reproduce the issue
Android version : 8.1.0

I tried checking Google play Service version with
`PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_PACKAGE, 0 ));` this is returning 17785019

I checked for google play store package availability

```
PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_PACKAGE, 0 )); this is giving package name `com.android.vending` translating to new GooglePlayStorePackageName.
```

Tried multiple other steps but not able to find exact root cause

Answer (score 2):

That method is deprecated for a reason. Just use the new recommended method.

FCM does not guarantee the generation of these tokens. But when it does generate the token, you are guaranteed to get the new token in the `onNewToken` method in your FCM service.

```kotlin
class NotificationService: FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
    }
}
```

excerpt from the documentation

> /**
>
> - There are two scenarios when onNewToken is called:
> - 1. When a new token is generated on initial app startup
> - 2. Whenever an existing token is changed
> - Under #2, there are three scenarios when the existing token is changed:
> - A) App is restored to a new device
> - B) User uninstalls/reinstalls the app
> - C) User clears app data
>   */

You can get the generated token on demand anywhere in your app using the new method. This method will only return the token if the initial generation was successful.

```kotlin
fun tryGetToken() {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.w(FCM_TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.exception)
                return@addOnCompleteListener
            }

            fcmToken = task.result
            Log.d(FCM_TAG, "FCM fetch success $fcmToken")
        }
```

Comment: Token is not getting generated because of security policy that is applied for the devices to run, But still not able to deduce which policy. Did a factory reset for the devices and token is getting generated in same device with same code. Problem is not associated with deprecated method(I do acknowledge deprecated method should be changed) but that is not the root cause

Comment: Is there any minimum version for Google play service and Play store in Android 8 for FCM to function properly? Or is there any mechanism to test FCM connectivity from code?

Comment: I will award the bounty as it will expire in 24hrs